# X-ray tracing not working for step function called from another lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions, aws-xray

My Workflow is like  :
 Lambda1 --> Step Machine (many different lambdas inside it) --> SQS (result of step machine is sent to SQS) --> Lambda (That is SQS triggered).

xray is not working in this case. It shows the broken trace, trace Id of lamda1 And step function is different.

Comment: I know that over certain services - say a Lambda sends an SNS notification, and a lambda function is subscribed to the topic and therefore gets invoked - the xray trace becomes "broken". It's likely to be the case for an SQS-triggered lambda as well.

Comment: Thanks @404 , I reached aws support and they confirmed that step function doesn't maintain the trace id of caller resource.  So you cant get the linked tracing of lambda --> step function --> lambda.
issue is already reported and they are working on it.